# How to prove that elements in the main diagonal of PD matrix are all positive?

Tags: matrices, matlab, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

*Reminder: As PD matrices are defined vector X is not the vector 0*

Given a positive definite matrix A which is symmetric
We need to prove that he following elements in the main diagonal are all positive

```
(A(1,1) A(2,2) ... A(n,n))
```

I started solving this but got stuck at the end, any help?
[image]

Comment: No, I am not talking about the diagonal entries of D but A

Comment: To the OP. The use in this website is, if one is satisfied with the answer, to upvote or to give the green ticket; otherwise we report what is not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

$A=[a_{i,j}]$ is the matrix of the scalar product $<x,y>=x^TAy$.

Then $<e_i,e_i>=||e_i||^2=e_i^TAe_i=a_{i,i}>0$.